# Mobile game made as website, used in app

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I'm thinking about making a mobile game (say something like Wordfeud).
Now I would like to publish this game on Android, iOS, WindowsPhone, facebook and normal browser.

I could go native on all these platforms.

BUT

Since a want it to be a multiplayer game, most of the functionality will be done via a c#.NET webservice with SOAP calls or something.

Now for another project i'm make a mobile website working in WebView (android) and the same website already works in an IOS app.

So.. why not make a jQuery/HTML5/.NET mobile website and some small apps just as a shell to get them in the marketplaces. That way everything will be in one place and updates/bugfixes will be a walk in the park.

What do you think?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [Apple Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html), you could see :

> Apps that are not very useful, unique, **are simply web sites bundled as Apps**, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected

You will be able to launch your android one, but you may have your iOS web bundle rejected.

I suggest to have a look to this page before posting to the app store

Comment: Interesting! I did not know Apple could ban apps that are just mobile websites. This is also something I need to look at, since we already have a IOS version that is just a website in an app "shell".

Comment: Apple was much more permissive in the past :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are 3 things I always see in html5 apps :
-very bad integration to the different platforms
-bad performances, web based is way slower than native.
-nightmare to maintain.

I strongly encourage you to go the native way if you want to do a quality app.
HTML5 is not all wrong. I think it is the right choice if there are big time/budget constraints and/or you don't care about the quality of the app (for exemple if it will be only used internally).

Final thought : why SOAP ?? REST is faster and is not harder to implement.

Comment: Yes it must be a quality app/game. Also the perfomance must be high, since I want users to stick around and not get frustrated by bad performance.

Comment: I advise you to look at the existing apps based on html5. I don't have a bias against this technology. I would like a lot to be able to just code an app once and run it everywhere... but I don't know ANY exemple of such an app that is of good quality.
Facebook has been one of the most vocal advocates of html5 in mobile apps... they are moving away from this tech and implementing pure native apps for iOS & Android.

Comment: Unity is a very good cross platform engine. But :
-I don't think it supports Facebook games (to verify I have no interest in this plateform so I am not sure)
-It is pretty good with 3D but sucks with 2D.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a lot of problems with this. If you look at tools that try too help you do this kind of thing, the most powerful ones being Google PlayN and Monkey. There are still a lot of semantic differences between a HTML/Flash/SilverLight game and a Mobile one, The most obvious being differences in input devices and screen resolution sizes.

It's also important to realize that the cost of integrating the different platforms (ie facebook vs. non-facbook, depending on what type of game you're making) may be significant.

Google PlayN: http://code.google.com/p/playn/

Monkey: http://www.monkeycoder.co.nz/

Comment: Yes, the resolution might be a problem.